# SQL Select Friends Change Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to select friend list with MemberID on MS SQL here is my code

```
    SELECT MemberID, FriendID,(Select Username From Members Where MemberID = Friends.FriendID) as Username FROM Friends WHERE MemberID = @MemberID
    UNION
    SELECT MemberID as FriendID, FriendID as MemberID,(Select Username From Members Where MemberID = Friends.MemberID) as Username FROM Friends WHERE FriendID = @MemberID
```

and the result is

```
MemberID    FriendID  
1           2
1           7
34          1
```

What should I do to change the last row to

```
MemberID    FriendID  
1           2
1           7
1           34
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  MemberID, FriendID
FROM    Friends
WHERE   MemberID = @MemberID
UNION ALL
SELECT  FriendID, MemberID
FROM    Friends
WHERE   FriendID = @MemberID
```

Comment: Yes I just figured it out, really dump question sorry (:

Comment: @KanerTUNCEL - Don't worry about it, I had my *"aha"* moment only after reading the answer 10 times <g>.